# .htaccess rewrite exception directories

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect everything app/webroot because of sructure of cakePHP except 2 folders (beqr and becoupon) which are separate apps
my .htaccess for now is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/beqr [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/becoupon [NC]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without using `RewriteCond`
.htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^beqr/(.*) -  [L]
   RewriteRule ^becoupon/(.*) -  [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```